# how to write regex starts and ends with particular string?

Tags: python, mysql, regex

How to write regex for this paricular situation. 
Here letters in [] is not fixed but letters without [] is fixed.

```
http://www.abc.com/fixed/[any small letters]/[anyletters]/fixed.html
```

Comment: what language is this for? Python or MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

```
http://www.abc.com/fixed/[a-z]+/[a-zA-Z]+/fixed.html
```

Possibly change to a more forgiving:

```
http://www.abc.com/fixed/[a-z]+/[^/]+/fixed.html
```

Comment: You forgot a `+` after `[a-zA-Z]` in the first example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that. One problem may be that they are not available in every language. For instance Javascript has only positive lookahead.

Oh, you mean something different... try this:

```
http://www.abc.com/fixed/[a-z]+/[\w\D^_]+/fixed.html
```

Comment: Careful, `\w` also matches digits and `_`.